# Macbook Pro 2017 - battery replaced but not charging

Tags: macbook-pro, battery, charging

i have replaced the battery of my macbook late 2016-2017, but i cannot let it charge. It keeps showing this when i turn it on

[image]

Even if i plug the charger, it keeps showing the same icon and won't charge.

I have tried the smc procedure but won't work...

Comment: You *personally* changed the battery yourself? If so are you sure the battery was good and from a reputable dealer? Are you sure you installed it correctly? Are you sure you didn't image anything during the replacement process?

Comment: Hi, yes, i have done it personally, following instructions from the ifixit website - battery bought on amazon with good reviews.

Comment: How long have you let it charge? New batteries are usually shipped at zero percent charged, at least in my experience.

Comment: Overnight, but when i plug the cable the logo posted above does not change - it usually turns into the same logo but without the plug picture.

Comment: so a reputable supplier and you did it yourself. there are two possibilities. 1) defective battery 2) Mac damaged during install. Id try returning the battery under warranty and have them ship you another. If THAT doesn't work then I would tend to go with, "damaged Mac installing new battery." Sorry...

Comment: I would try two other things. 1) Make sure the battery connection to the motherboard is tight. 2) Make sure there's nothing wrong with the charger or the charger cable (I've had a cat chew through the charger cable, so I know problems there are possible). If neither of those are it, then your battery is bad.

Comment: I've managed to do it - i bought a new flex cable, because I noticed it looked a bit damaged. BUT: battery does not charge when the macbook is connected to the power source. I tried the SMC, but it didn't help.